# how to select a div or class in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine

I'm trying to findelement 'div' e make a loop to find another elements but its not working.

already check few tutorials and forum before I asked so please, I'm for so patient for that!

here is the html and js code.

hrml:

```
      <li><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success referral-btn" href="https://www.bizimply.com/referral.html">Referral Rewards</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown user-settings-dropdown open">
        <a class="user-avatar-plus" href="/edit.1833?mode=edit_profile"><img class="img-circle" src="/assets/plus-c30429dd2e8d9d3cc89851b2b06b74ab.png" alt="Plus"></a>

      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Paulo Gomes
        <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
      </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/edit.1833?mode=edit_profile">Your Profile</a>
        </li>


          <li>
            <a href="/stores">Location Setup</a>
          </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/settings/725/edit">Settings</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/subscription/plans/current">Plans &amp; Billing</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/company_apps">App Center</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/roles/employees">Employee Roles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/reports">Reports</a>
```

js:

```
it ('Profile settings', function(done) {
        var username = this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.id('user_user_name')).sendKeys('paulo@bizimply.com');

        var user_password = this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.id('user_password')).sendKeys('123456');

        var element = this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.id('sign-in-button'));

        var edit_profile = this.driver.findElement(selenium.By.css('dropdown user-settings-dropdown'));

        // this.profile=true;
        element.click();
        edit_profile.click();sendKeys();


        this.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toContain('/edit');
            done();
        });
    });
```